# Assignments using objectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c

Why would this work:

```
firstItem = @"Some value";
```

And this result in an error when I try to access the NSString firstItem property:

```
NSArray *values = [dict allVaues];
firstItem = (NSString *)[values objectAtIndex:0];
```

From the .m:

```
@synthesize firstItem;
```

From the .h

```
NSString *firstItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *firstItem;
```

NOTE: If I NSLog from the method I set this property it shows the correct values for the erring example, but later on the data is not available.  I assume I need to set the values explicitly and not as references to my NSMutableDictionary that is out of scope.  Any advice?

Comment: Is `firstItem` a regular class property of type `copy` or `retain`, or just a local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you're not actually using the property. You're assigning the ivar directly instead. If you change your `@synthesize` line to say

```
@synthesize firstItem=_firstItem;
```

then you'll notice that your code using `firstItem` will no longer compile. That's a good sign that you're inadvertently ignoring the property accessors. You should be using `self.firstItem = foo` instead.